# Change WSDL for WCF Service based on an environment

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, wcf-endpoint

I've `WCF` service and `.net` client on local machine. I've generated `wsdl` for the client. It has bunch of files like `.svcinfo, .wsdl, .xsd, .svcmap, .cs`. Some of the files have address of the service `https://localhost:12345/foo/bar.svc`

Eventually the service and the client will be deployed to testing and then to production. At that time do I need to regenerate the `wsdl` for the client to reflect the correct urls in the `.svcinfo, .wsdl, .xsd, .svcmap, .cs` files? Or changing the `endpoint` address in the client config file is enough?

Answer (score 0):

You have absolutely no need to do such a thing. We usually expose metadata information about a WCF service through its metadata endpoint. The client can then generate a client proxy class by adding a service reference, and the proxy class can implement calls to the service.

```
<services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <!--metadata service endpoint-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--Enable service metadata publish-->
          <serviceMetadata/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client-side.
[image]
Optionally, we can also publish service data in the form of HTTP/https, just configure the properties below.

```
  <!--Enable service metadata publish-->
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

By which, the client could directly download the WSDL/SingleWSDL file, so that generate the client proxy class manually.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.